# How to extract data from .csv file with a given format in .json file in python?

Tags: python, json, csv

A very new person to python data analysis, and an aspiring data analyst  I am trying to extract data from a given CSV file, and it has been given in a format which is given in another .json file.

I am not able to figure out how exaclty do I start this procedure?

This is my data.csv file sample text:

data.csv

```
v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11,v12,v13
2,1,3,3|6|1|2|5,5,1,1,4,4|1|3|2|5,2,3|5|4|2,1,2
2,2,2,1|6|5|2|3|4,1,5,4,4,4|3|5|2|1,3,3|2|4|5,2,3
1,2,1,3|2|1|5,4,2,4,3,1|2|4|3|5,2,4|3,1,1
2,3,3,6|2|1|3|5|4,5,2,1,1,3|4|5,2,4,4,1
```

format.json

```
[
  {
    "type": 1,
    "name": "Gender",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "Male"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "Female"
      }
    ],
    "variable": "v1"
  },
  {
    "type": 1,
    "name": "Age Group",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "13-18"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "19-26"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "27-35"
      }
    ],
    "variable": "v2"
  },
  {
    "type": 1,
    "name": "City",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "Delhi"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "Jaipur"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "Mumbai"
      }
    ],
    "variable": "v3"
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "name": "Clothing purchased",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "Jeans"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "Shirt"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "Trouser"
      },
      {
        "code": 4,
        "label": "Sweater"
      },
      {
        "code": 5,
        "label": "Coat"
      },
      {
        "code": 6,
        "label": "Shorts"
      }
    ],
    "variable": "v4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Price Justified",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "Extremely Agree"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "Agree"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "Neither Agree nor disagree"
      },
      {
        "code": 4,
        "label": "Disagree"
      },
      {
        "code": 5,
        "label": "Extremely Disagree"
      }
    ],
    "type": 1,
    "variable": "v5"
  },
  {
    "name": "Good quality",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "Extremely Agree"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "Agree"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "Neither Agree nor disagree"
      },
      {
        "code": 4,
        "label": "Disagree"
      },
      {
        "code": 5,
        "label": "Extremely Disagree"
      }
    ],
    "type": 1,
    "variable": "v6"
  },
  {
    "name": "Occupation",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "Govt. Service"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "Private Service"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "Business"
      },
      {
        "code": 4,
        "label": "Student"
      },
      {
        "code": 5,
        "label": "Unemployed"
      }
    ],
    "type": 1,
    "variable": "v7"
  },
  {
    "name": "Salary Range",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "0-5L"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "5L-10L"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "10L-15L"
      },
      {
        "code": 4,
        "label": "15L-20L"
      },
      {
        "code": 5,
        "label": "20L and more"
      }
    ],
    "type": 1,
    "variable": "v8"
  },
  {
    "name": "If new Product introducted what would you buy",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "Tie"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "Caps"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "Socks"
      },
      {
        "code": 4,
        "label": "Poncho"
      },
      {
        "code": 5,
        "label": "Scarves"
      }
    ],
    "type": 2,
    "variable": "v9"
  },
  {
    "name": "Rate",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "1 Star"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "2 Star"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "3 Star"
      },
      {
        "code": 4,
        "label": "4 Star"
      },
      {
        "code": 5,
        "label": "5 Star"
      }
    ],
    "type": 1,
    "variable": "v10"
  },
  {
    "name": "what you didnt like",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "Staff behaviour"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "Clothing Variety"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "Cleanliness"
      },
      {
        "code": 4,
        "label": "Location"
      },
      {
        "code": 5,
        "label": "Price"
      }
    ],
    "type": 2,
    "variable": "v11"
  },
  {
    "name": "Shopping Experience",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "1"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "2"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "3"
      },
      {
        "code": 4,
        "label": "4"
      },
      {
        "code": 5,
        "label": "5"
      }
    ],
    "type": 1,
    "variable": "v12"
  },
  {
    "name": "Did you avail discount",
    "options": [
      {
        "code": 1,
        "label": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "No"
      },
      {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "didn't know"
      }
    ],
    "type": 1,
    "variable": "v13"
  }
]
```

Any kind of help or tutorial would be much appreciated, also, being a python developer I will be able to understand any kind of python code, so code answers are also appreciated.

Please note: The top row is the Header for the variables used for each question and as mentioned earlier few questions are multiple choice question so for them the response is captured in the form of pipe separated codes (‘|’) in the above row [variables v4, v9 and v11 are multiple choice variables]

Comment: first you have to read csv to memory - you have module `pandas` or `csv` for this. `pandas` is very popular for data analysis. But later you have to write own codel to create python's directory with expected data. If you have directory then you can use module `json` to save it in file.

Comment: Did you make any code attempts to solve this problem which you can show us?

Comment: @furas Yes, I was able to read the csv file using the csv module into a variable called data, now I do not know how to categorize the extracted data according to the given format. Do I first split each row by commas, then store them in different variables ? hmm... thanks for the idea!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Coming right up..

Comment: Could you understand what represent the values in the csv file, and what the `|` stand for in it? If the answer is yes but you do not know how to actually process multivalue data, I am afraid for the question to be off topic because too broad.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have updated the question with that detail. I forgot about adding  that. Like I said sir, I am a developer myself, but I have never done data analysis and do not know how people do this, I just need to know the method  commonly used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in each data types. Then you can iterate through each column, matching it with the corresponding index value in the json/dictionary to make a mapping dictionary. Then that mapping dictionary to replace the values with the associated label.

```
import pandas as pd
import json


def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text


data = pd.read_csv('C:/data.csv')

with open('C:/format.json') as json_file:  
    data_format = json.load(json_file)


cols = list(data.columns)

for col in cols:

    data[col] = data[col].astype(str)
    # Get index of the dictionary where the label value matches the column
    idx = next((index for (index, d) in enumerate(data_format) if d["variable"] == col), None)
    temp_dict = data_format[idx]

    map_dict = {}
    for each in temp_dict['options']:
        map_dict[str(each['code'])] = each['label']

    data[col]=data[col].apply(lambda x: replace_all(x, map_dict))
```

**Output:**

```
print (data.to_string())
       v1         v2      v3                                       v4                  v5                  v6             v7                  v8                             v9     v10                                          v11 v12          v13
0  Female  127-35-18  Mumbai          Trouser|Shorts|Jeans|Shirt|Coat  Extremely Disagree     Extremely Agree  Govt. Service  120L and moreL-20L  Poncho|Tie|Socks|Caps|Scarves  2 Star  Cleanliness|Price|Location|Clothing Variety   1           No
1  Female      19-26  Jaipur  Jeans|Shorts|Coat|Shirt|Trouser|Sweater     Extremely Agree  Extremely Disagree        Student  120L and moreL-20L  Poncho|Socks|Scarves|Caps|Tie  3 Star  Cleanliness|Clothing Variety|Location|Price   2  didn't know
2    Male      19-26   Delhi                 Trouser|Shirt|Jeans|Coat            Disagree               Agree        Student  10L-120L and moreL  Tie|Caps|Poncho|Socks|Scarves  2 Star                         Location|Cleanliness   1          Yes
3  Female      27-35  Mumbai  Shorts|Shirt|Jeans|Trouser|Coat|Sweater  Extremely Disagree               Agree  Govt. Service     0-20L and moreL           Socks|Poncho|Scarves  2 Star                                     Location   4          Yes
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much! Now I will decode this so I can do it myself and understand why and how you did it.

Comment: Oh ya. Good catch. I’ll have to debug to see what happened there.

Comment: Ahh I see what happened. It replaced the 3, within the 13-18, since ‘3’:’27-35’ in that map_dict. So it did 1<27-35>- 18. I’ll have to rework the function

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but it did not affect any other field name like that so it was weird ..

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html For basics of pandas, a powerful data analysis lybrary,

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html to understand IO management,

FYI you can load everythig to a `pandas.DataFrame` with method `read_csv` and `read_json` (careful with orient argument) then transform to the desired format `to_csv, to_json`